# Как проверить валидность веденной почты HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть один из input типа email, надо проверить его на правильность веденной почты, pattern не работает

```
            <input
              id="inputMail"
              class="popup__input-text"
              required
              type="email"
              placeholder="E-mail"
```

Comment: Что именно вы считаете за «правильность» и почему pattern не работает?

Comment: @andreymal, на самом деле, я догадываюсь, почему pattern не работает в Хроме. Но в вопросе про кириллицу в домене ничего нет.

Answer (score 2):

Этого достаточно:

```html
<form>
  <input type=email name=smth required>
  <input type=submit value=Ok>
</form>
```